# How do you pronounce "O'Nions"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm going to a talk by [Keith O'Nions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_O%27Nions) and I'm wondering how to pronounce his name.

Oh neons?
Onions?

Comment: Are you presenting him to an audience? Then ask him personally beforehand. If not, listen to how the presenter pronounces it.

Comment: I have reopened this question. Anyone famous enough to have a Wikipedia article is famous enough to have a question here on how to pronounce their name without it being closed for being "too localized". Humph!

Comment: ... *especially* if the Wikipedia article doesn't have a pronunciation key.

Comment: @Mitch This is more so I can tell my friends. Sorry I'm busy, I'm going to listen to Keith ??? talk.

Comment: When did having a Wikipedia article become a measure of fame?

Comment: This is not about English, this is about how one particular person pronounces his name.

Comment: I have reopened this question *again*. How names are pronounced is part of the language.

Comment: @nohat: Having a Wikipedia page is a very low standard; my understanding is that it just means that some professional publication somewhere wrote an article on you at least once. It seems people think that's not enough to immortalize your name as an English lexical item, *any more than would be a nonce word that occurs in a single work*.

Comment: I can't think of a better standard, and it's one we've used before, so as far as I'm concerned, it stands. Further, the question is about the surname in general, of which Keith O'Nions is but one example of many http://www.192.com/atoz/people/surnames/o'nions/50/

Comment: @nohat - No, it's about how one person (or one branch of a family) pronounces the name. By the standards of ordinary Anglified spelling of Gaelic names, he pronounces it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess `Oh-Nyuns` (rhymes with lions).  Of course, the best thing is to make sure you attend the beginning of the talk and listen to the introduction. :)

Comment: That's correct. Listen just after 25 seconds of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhAeXj1xMcc) for the announcer to introduce him.

Comment: That's assuming *this* announcer knows how to do it.

Comment: A decent announcer will know his onions.